# ElasticSearch not returning results for queries with whitespaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query :

```
{
"from":0,
"size::1000,
"query":
{
"multi_match":{
"query":"ABC XYZ",
"fields":["displayname"],"fuzziness":0
}
},
"sort":[]
}
```

I am not getting results. query return results if I am searching for a string without white spaces like "ABC". What is wrong with my settings or queries?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index and also a sample document that you expect to match?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "displayname": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "displayname":"ABC ABC"
}
{
  "displayname":"ABC XYZ"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "ABC XYZ",
      "fields": [
        "displayname.keyword"
      ],
      "fuzziness": 0
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66241563",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "displayname": "ABC XYZ"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Arshad Arshad please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?